# Stacked Bar Chart Python from pivot/groupby table

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, visualization, stacked-bar-chart

This is a sample data. How can I get Sum Amount in Y axis with quarter as stacked and region and year on X axis.

```
Region Year   Quarter  Sum Amount
 A     2016     1       100
                2       80
                3       70
                4       10
       2017     1       90
                2       50
                3       60
                4       30
B      2016     1       120
                2       80
                3       90
                4       20
       2017     2       80
                3       100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# data
random.seed(365)
data = {'Year': [random.choice([2016, 2017]) for _ in range(1000)],
        'Region': [random.choice(['A', 'B']) for _ in range(1000)],
        'Quarter': [random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4]) for _ in range(1000)],
        'Value': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(1000)]}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby
gb = df.groupby(['Region', 'Year', 'Quarter'])['Value'].sum().unstack()

# or pivot_table; use either groupby or pivot_table
# gb = df.pivot_table(index=['Region', 'Year'], columns='Quarter', values='Value', aggfunc='sum')

     Quarter      1   2   3   4
Region  Year                
     A  2016    306 279 221 261
        2017    209 250 292 415
     B  2016    262 296 261 260
        2017    209 349 272 315

# plot
gb.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.legend(title='Quarter', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]